# gsub to split a string at -

Tags: r, gsub

I have a bunch of values in a column as follows.

```
             3145-MY     
             32441-TX   
             3245-NYC  
             416356-TPK  
             4H22-BLT      
             %ABC-ROCIST
```

I am trying to split these values at - , I want everything before - , the output should look like this

```
             3145    
             32441   
             3245 
             416356  
             4H22     
             %ABC
```

I tried using gsub but am little confused, need help.

Comment: `sub("-.+","",vectorname)` - though I'm sure this has been answered before.

Comment: @thelatemail, worked like a charm. :-)

Comment: Can also use `strsplit` with `sapply`: `sapply(strsplit(vectorname), "-"), "[", 1)`

Comment: @PeterDee, I might be wrong, but i ready that when dealing with large datasets gsub and sub works best ? :)

Comment: @Science11 Well they both "work" - I think though that the quickest method is with `(g)sub`.

Comment: @PeterDee , ah thats what I thought :)

Answer (score 0):

One of many methods: 
In the `Reshape2` package you can use `colsplit` to split the column on a given character.

```
df <- data.frame(var=c("3145-MY" ,    
    "32441-TX" ,  
    "3245-NYC"  ,
    "416356-TPK " ,
    "4H22-BLT"    ,  
    "%ABC-ROCIST"
))

library(reshape2)
df <- colsplit(df$var, "-", c("left", "right"))
```

which gives

```
> df
    left  right
1   3145     MY
2  32441     TX
3   3245    NYC
4 416356   TPK 
5   4H22    BLT
6   %ABC ROCIST
```